# JTree how to know a node has been expanded but not selected

Tags: java, swing, selection, jtree, expansion

JTree provides SelectionListener and ExpansionListener.
But as far as I can see when you only expand a node (click the +/- icon) a selection event is fired as well.
1) If I click on the expansion icon I get 1 event for the expansion + 1 event for the selection
2) If I click on a node itself I get only 1 event for the selection

Any way to NOT having the selection event fired when the user expand a node?

Or... how could I detect an expansion ONLY (no selection)? I want to execute a time-consuming operation ONLY when a node is really selected and do nothing on just expansion (except have the node expanded in the GUI)
Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: your last paragraph sounds as a contradiction in itself: _expension only - time-consuming operation when really selected_ Please clarify.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a way so that I can do nothing when a user expand a node (it will just expand the node in the tree) and let me update another part of the GUI only when the user select a node in the tree.

Comment: My app includes several trees. When you click on a node in the tree, the app retrieve data from a DB, calculate things, generate graphics etc. This takes some times. Even folders are associated with information like this. The problem is: when you need to expand 10 folders nodes to access another node where you need to get the data I don't want to get data from all the 10 parent folders first (too much calculation for nothing).

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the `TreeWillExpandListener` interface to intercept the `TreeExpansionEvent`, as shown in [*How to Write a Tree-Will-Expand Listener*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treewillexpandlistener.html). [`TreeExpandEventDemo2`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treewillexpandlistener.html#eg) is an example.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this will prevent from firing a selection event is it? when a node is selected in my app, many informations are retrieve from DB and figures computed. this takes a lot of time (more than 2 seconds). What I need is my users to be able to expand a complete branch (many nodes) without having to update those 5 nodes information... The best for me would be that when you just expand a node by clicking the + icon (and not clicking on the node itself) no selection event is fired.

Comment: `TreeExpandEventDemo2` worked for me; this [example](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/6692) uses `SwingWorker` to back-fill the model.

Comment: Thanks! This example is very interesting and I may implement a loazy loading mechanism like this in the future. But for now this does not answer my simpler question. My tree is 100% loaded and all the childs are already loaded in the tree. I'm just trying to differentiate expand from selection to not process nodes that are opened through the + icon of the tree...

Comment: no idea guys? I don't understand why the opening of a node fires also a selection event... looks really weird to me.

Comment: `TreeExpandEventDemo2` does not implement `TreeSelectionListener`, but you might add one to see the effect.